# Pglogical replication sets not working as expected

Tags: postgresql, replication

I am trying to setup up pglogical replication. I have a table which has around 4 rows in the provider server.

```
=========
employee_id |     visitor_email     | vistor_id |        date         |             message          
-------------+-----------------------+-----------+---------------------+--------------------------
       1 | roshan@gmail.com      |         1 | 2016-08-24 00:00:00 | This is the first test.
       2 | roshan@myrepublic.net |         2 | 2016-08-24 00:00:00 | This is the second test.
       3 | roshan@myrepublic.net |         3 | 2016-08-24 00:00:00 | This is the third test.
       4 | roshan@myrepublic.net |         4 | 2016-08-24 00:00:00 | This is the fourth test.
  ===============================
```

After creating the above mentioned table. I have created a replication set in the provider . Then I configured the subscriber node and the subscription. Ideally, I should see the 4 rows from the provider table in my subscriber, but I am only seeing the table structure in subscriber, not the data.  If I add a new row in the provider table as follows

```
INSERT INTO employees (employee_id, visitor_email, date, message) VALUES (5, 'roshan@myrepublic.net', current_date, 'This is the fifth test.');
```

Now, I am able to see the last added row in my subscriber table. All the other 4 rows which were added in the beginning are still missing. What am I doing wrong here?

Does it mean that only the data which was created after the creation of replication_sets will be considered? How to add the whole content of a table to a replication set.?

Any help would be much appreciated.?

Regards,
Muhammed Roshan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can issue the resynchronise_table command to pull everything across. All subsequent inserts will be ok as you've found.

Use this function to do so:

```
pglogical.alter_subscription_resynchronize_table(subscription_name name, relation regclass)
```

Also you could have passed "synchronize_data" during your initial sync:

For more information see 2.3 in the following document:

https://2ndquadrant.com/en/resources/pglogical/pglogical-docs/

Comment: No problem. Consider accepting the answer if it worked for you. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to replicate the sequences from my provider to subscriber. I created different replication sets and subscriptions for both tables and sequences. Once I start the subscription from the subscriber, the tables are getting replicated without any issues, but the respective sequences are not getting replicated. The **last_value** field in the sequence still remains as 1 even though I have more than one entries in the corresponding table. I read from the pglogical documentation that I can issue **synchronize_sequence** function . What is the "SELECT" query for this?

Comment: SELECT synchronize_sequence('sequence_name'); However it needs to be completed on the "master" which will issue the sync to subscribers I believe.